# Error executing cat command from Java using Process on a filename containing a space

Tags: java, unix

Using the code:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new StringBuffer("cat ").append("../dir1").append("\"").append(File.separator).append("dir2").append(File.separator).append("hello text.xml").append("\""));
```

Fails with the error:

```
cat Error: cat: "../dir1/dir2/hello: No such file or directory
cat Error: cat: text.xml": No such file or directory
```

The actual file name is `hello text.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape whitespace by using `hello\ text.xml`

Comment: yeah i tried this but it's also not working. still the file name gets break after that slash.

Answer (score 0):

Try with double quotes like "hello text.xml" . It worked for me.

Comment: I tried this too. In Unix it's working fine but when am running it with Process from Java, it's failing with the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for the above Problem.
we can write the Command into a Shell Script file and execute the same through Process from Java Program and it's working fine. :)